# What are the accepted units for the <img> width attribute?

Tags: html, css

I'm new to html so I'm a bit lost when I read that we can change the dimensions of the images through CSS or the width, height attribute.

For the width height attribute, some posts say that only pixels are accepted. But somehow, percentage also seems to work fine for my code.

However, when I tried using vw and vh, the image sized strangly.

so,

1. What are the accepted units for width and height attribute?
2. Is CSS recommended over width and height, for changing the dimensions of the images?

Many thanks.

Comment: https://html.com/attributes/img-width/

Comment: The attributes have a different use to the CSS properties of the same name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The accepted units for the width and height attributes of an HTML img element are pixels. You give the number of pixels, but don't put the 'px'.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Img)

> width
> The intrinsic width of the image in pixels. Must be an integer without a unit.

It is possible to get confused between these attributes and the use of CSS properties of the same names. While the attributes had more use probably when load times were longer (they allowed the correct space for the img to be saved in the page) they may be making a comeback, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/images/aspect_ratio_mapping which ends with:

> — eliminating another piece of jank from web layout! There is no need for a web developer to do anything special to their code to take advantage of this, besides returning to the habit of using width and height attributes in their HTML.