scaling img with svg-content to font-size, why does it not respect my em-setting?
The simple html:
<html><head>
  <style>
     body {font-size:1em;}
     img {display:inline-block; border:1px solid #0f0;}
  </style>
</head><body>
  <p>Mm<img height="10em" src="PregnantWoman.svg" />Mm</p>
</body></html>

The svg:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
   viewBox="0 0 119 258"
   preserveAspectRatio = "xMidYMid meet"
   version="1.1"
   id="svg1"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs
     id="defs1" />
  <path
     id="path"
     style="fill:#2ea4e3;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none"
     d="M 69 0 L 66 0 C 56 1 50 5 43 11 C 35 19 22 35 35 48 C 37 50 38 46 40 48 C 41
     50 41 52 42 54 C 43 57 43 60 43 63 C 44 65 47 64 47 65 C 48 70 58 76 58 76 C 58
     76 61 75 63 74 C 62 72 60 75 58 75 C 54 72 50 70 49 64 C 48 63 45 64 44 63 C 45
     56 45 52 43 47 C 44 44 47 44 49 43 C 53 45 53 48 56 51 C 66 64 84 66 93 79 C 98
     85 103 97 102 109 C 102 115 98 122 95 128 C 87 145 75 163 75 186 C 75 211 89 231
     77 257 L 87 257 C 103 231 75 204 80 175 C 82 165 87 155 91 147 C 95 138 100 130
     105 122 C 106 128 107 133 107 140 C 110 136 111 131 112 126 C 115 108 120 87 118
     64 C 117 30 103 -1 69 0 Z M 82 85 C 77 86 73 93 71 97 C 66 108 63 122 60 135 C
     58 141 57 148 55 154 C 52 159 40 168 34 173 C 27 179 21 186 14 192 C 30 183 43
     168 58 156 C 67 133 67 102 82 85 Z M 72 91 C 67 101 47 106 36 114 C 31 118 26
     126 31 135 C 21 148 4 159 5 185 C 5 187 4 191 7 192 C 10 192 9 186 10 184 C 13
     162 24 148 39 137 C 25 110 67 110 72 91 Z M 92 116 C 81 135 81 160 66 173 C 58
     180 48 184 39 189 C 35 192 30 195 26 198 C 23 200 17 203 17 208 C 19 208 18 205
     19 205 C 28 201 37 195 47 189 C 55 184 67 179 73 172 C 78 165 81 155 84 146 C
     87 137 90 127 92 116 Z M 1 194 C -4 205 5 213 13 215 C 8 210 -1 205 1 194 Z M
     21 215 C 15 224 12 242 14 257 C 15 259 16 257 19 257 C 19 245 16 226 21 215 Z"
    />
</svg>

The svg has a viewbox of 119x258, right?
That means that 258 svg-units are 100% of the svgs vertical viewable size and 119 svg-units are 100% percent of the svgs horizontal viewable size, right?
So why is img height="10em" not giving this svg an effective height of 10em? Where is my thinking going wrong?

<img> width and height attributes expect pixel-based value. You can define the em-based height via CSS or inline style attribute. To be fair: most browsers tolerate % percentages as well - but I assume this was rather implemented for compatibility reasons with browsers like ie. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68238174/what-are-the-accepted-units-for-the-img-width-attribute
